# rewriting windows .bat to AppleScript or UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, applescript

I was trying to rewrite a bit of code, but scripting languages are too weird to me... Can someone help me with rewrite? I can't even get the current folder path from current file path... It's windows .bat and I would like to run it on my Mac.
Thanks!

```
@ECHO off

SET CVICENIA=cvicenia
SET DST_CVICENIA=web
SET CONVERT_UTIL=java -cp . transform student.xsl

REM -------------------- REMOVE DESTINATION DIRS ---------------------

rmdir /S /Q %DST_CVICENIA%

REM -------------------- CVICENIA ---------------------

mkdir %DST_CVICENIA%

xcopy /I style %DST_CVICENIA%\style

FOR /d %%I IN (%CVICENIA%\*) DO (
  mkdir %DST_CVICENIA%\%%~nI
  copy %CVICENIA%\%%~nI %DST_CVICENIA%\%%~nI\
  %CONVERT_UTIL% %CVICENIA%\%%~nI\index.xml %DST_CVICENIA%\%%~nI\index.html
  del %DST_CVICENIA%\%%~nI\index.xml
)

REM copy %CVICENIA%\index.html %DST_CVICENIA%\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself...

```
on run

   display dialog "Wait for the end"

   set CURRENT_DIR to POSIX path of (do shell script "dirname " & POSIX path of ((path to me) as Unicode text)) & "/" as string

   set CONVERT_UTIL to "java -cp . transform student.xsl"
   set DST_CVICENIA to CURRENT_DIR & "web"
   set CVICENIA to CURRENT_DIR & "cvicenia"

   tell application "Finder"
       try
           delete folder (DST_CVICENIA as POSIX file)
       end try
       make new folder at (CURRENT_DIR as POSIX file) with properties {name:"web"}
       copy folder (CURRENT_DIR & "/style" as POSIX file) to folder (DST_CVICENIA as POSIX file)

       set CVICENIA_LIST to get name of folders of folder (CVICENIA as POSIX file)
       repeat with I in CVICENIA_LIST

           make new folder at (DST_CVICENIA as POSIX file) with properties {name:I}

           set DST_CVICENIA_I to DST_CVICENIA & "/" & I
           set CVICENIA_I to CVICENIA & "/" & I

           copy items of folder (CVICENIA_I as POSIX file) to folder (DST_CVICENIA_I as POSIX file)

           do shell script "cd " & CURRENT_DIR & "\n" & CONVERT_UTIL & " " & CVICENIA_I & "/index.xml " & DST_CVICENIA_I & "/index.html"

           delete item (DST_CVICENIA_I & "/index.xml" as POSIX file)

       end repeat

   end tell

   display dialog "End"

end run
```

Comment: Accept your own answer so that the question becomes answered.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't really about the scripting language itself, because the only part of that script that uses the scripting language is the `for` loop. You could probably replace that with a `find -depth 1` command, but a `for` loop in bash looks like this:

```
for i in myFolder/*; do
  #blah
  #blah
done
```

What you *really* need to find out is how to replace functionality of things like `mkdir` and `xcopy` in your bash script. For that you need to understand what the various flags you use in this script do, and how you can mimic their behaviour in options to, e.g. `mkdir`, `cp` and `rm`.